# how to record selenium webdriver test executions in python on window x64

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests

Using python binding selenium3 webdriver for test automation, to record execution steps using castro but it is failing on Windows 7 x64.

Is there any other library or module which can be used for recording purpose

Code with castro

```
from castro import Castro
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep

def my_video_record():
    castroObject = Castro(filename="video/mytest.swf")
    castroObject.start()
    firefoxDriver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="firefox_geckodriver64bit/geckodriver")
    firefoxDriver.get("https://www.python.org")
    assert "Python" in firefoxDriver.title
    sleep(1)
    firefoxDriver.quit()
    castroObject.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    my_video_record()
```

But it throws error on my Windows7 x64

```
Socket error: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "D:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\castro\lib\pyvnc2swf\vnc2swf.py", line 611, in main
    merge=merge, debug=debug, reconnect=reconnect)
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\castro\lib\pyvnc2swf\vnc2swf.py", line 429, in vnc2swf
    client.loop()
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\castro\lib\pyvnc2swf\rfb.py", line 489, in loop
    if not self.loop1(): break
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\castro\lib\pyvnc2swf\rfb.py", line 276, in loop1
    self.request_update()
  File "D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\castro\lib\pyvnc2swf\rfb.py", line 551, in request_update
    self.send('\x03\x01' + pack('>HHHH', *self.clipping))
AttributeError: RFBNetworkClient instance has no attribute 'clipping'
```

Comment: Are you using vncauth on vnc server?

Answer (score 8):

I do not recommend using castro. It's really outdated, I've tried using it in my own tests and did get it running but it was too unstable.

I'm currently using [ffmpeg](https://www.google.pl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjB7IGoiYDSAhXMORoKHUQvAOIQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fffmpeg.org%2F&usg=AFQjCNEMqXt-KGXX4L_U95FXMiJ8a9A9QA&sig2=0CLzqw2Duh3A1_w7lsuBvw) together with [screen-capture-recorder](https://www.google.pl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjDwI-xiYDSAhWFbBoKHV67BNQQFggfMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Frdp%2Fscreen-capture-recorder-to-video-windows-free&usg=AFQjCNFOfN55gVSFX6koAfwdNlEcVRqakQ&sig2=frl34Mb0K8rq4N0Gi38p0w) (screen recording software) and it works like a charm. It allows you to set the framerate, resolution, bitrate as well as chose different video codec.

The code looks like this :

```
from subprocess import Popen
from subprocess import call

cmd = 'ffmpeg -y -rtbufsize 2000M -f dshow  -i video="screen-capture-recorder" -s 1920x1080 -b:v 512k -r 20 -vcodec libx264 test.avi'

def terminate(process):
    if process.poll() is None:
        call('taskkill /F /T /PID ' + str(process.pid))

videoRecording = Popen(cmd) # start recording

terminate(videoRecording)   # terminates recording
```

Comment: Do I need to install both of them?  ffmpeg and  screen-capture-recorder?

Comment: @Bomin, yes you do.

Comment: do they support comman line installation?  For example, I can install them from "chocolatey"

Comment: Video capture is fine but does not seem to capture audio. The ffmpeg is functional. What can be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

**I created custom class to record selenium window**

## Code :

#### selenium_addons.py

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver import WebDriver
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
import cv2
import numpy as np


class Record():
    def __init__(self, object, file_name="video",size=None, flags=cv2.IMREAD_COLOR):
        self.object = object
        self.flags = flags
        self.size=size
        fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
        if self.size is None:
            self.size = self.get_frame().shape[:2][::-1]
        self.out = cv2.VideoWriter(f"{file_name}.avi", fourcc, 8.0, self.size)

    def get_frame(self):
        try:
            if isinstance(self.object, WebDriver):
                im_arr = np.frombuffer(
                    self.object.get_screenshot_as_png(), dtype=np.uint8)
            elif isinstance(self.object, WebElement):
                im_arr = np.frombuffer(
                    self.object.screenshot_as_png, dtype=np.uint8)
        except:
            return False
        self.frame = cv2.imdecode(im_arr, flags=self.flags)
        return self.frame

    def capture(self):
        frame = cv2.resize(self.frame, self.size)
        self.out.write(frame)
        return frame

    def save(self):
        self.out.release()
```

## Usage :

```
from selenium_addons import Record # Import Record class from selenium_addons.py file which contain above code
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
service = Service(
    "C:/Users/Roshan Yadav/Documents/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
try:
    driver.get("chrome://dino")
except:
    pass
driver.maximize_window()
# to capture whole screen pass driver object as below OR to capture element pass webelement object
window = Record(driver, file_name="firearch")

while True:
    frame = window.get_frame()  # Get New Frame
    if frame is False:
        # if browser closed or quit (window.get_frame() return False ) then save captured frames and break loop
        window.save()
        break
    # capture coming frame
    window.capture()
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you have not enabled vnc loop back connection.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium provides us with the feature to run the automation code/suite and record the output as a video and save it on your system. This video can then be shared with anyone who can see what the automation is doing. First of all, to enable video recording, we need to download some important jars. They are freely available to download from Google. Below are the jars to be downloaded. These are the latest version available, any other version can also be downloaded:

ATUReporter_Selenium_testNG_5.1.1
ATUTestRecorder_2.1

You can find the complete code in below link:
https://mytechdevice.com/how-to-record-video-of-automation-output-in-selenium/

Answer (score 0):

I use **Chrome** for such a presentation and **record a performance profile with screenshots by developer tools**. One can then extract [screenshots as a GIF file from the profile](https://hospodarets.com/demos/chrome-timeline-to-gif/). The final result looks like in this demo, which tests page search:

[image: selenium_demo]