# Using a headless Chrome instance as an OBS source

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome-headless, obs

Would it be possible to use an instance of headless Chrome that is created by Selenium in Python3

Here is the code that i'm using to launch headless chrome.

```
options = Options()
options.set_headless(True)
driver_chrome = webdriver.Chrome(options=options) 
driver_chrome.get("http://google.com/")
```

as a source in the broadcasting software OBS? I know that OBS is able to detect regular instances of non-headless chrome by using Window Capture, but I'm not sure how to apply this to an instance of headless Chrome.

If there is no immediate solution, would one be able to point me in the right direction in what steps to take that would allow this to happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to record selenium webdriver test executions in python on window x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41885914/how-to-record-selenium-webdriver-test-executions-in-python-on-window-x64)

Comment: It’s different. I’m not trying to record it necessarily, but instead use the browser instance as a source in OBS.

Comment: You are trying to capture video using OBS. Am i right ?

Comment: Not really? I’m trying to use it as a live stream source for OBS, not direct video that I’m going to save on my desktop. OBS is already to use ‘Window Capture’ to get non-headless chrome as a video source.