# Is there any code for recording python selenium test, and to get video or recorded gif as an output?

Tags: python, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, video-recording

I am trying to record video of python selenium test execution!
I tryed Castro, but it seems Castro is outdated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to record selenium webdriver test executions in python on window x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41885914/how-to-record-selenium-webdriver-test-executions-in-python-on-window-x64)

Comment: No, this doens't help.

Comment: @AleksandarCiric, how does the link above not help? It gives you two options of recording, and also gives you some code to go along. Did you try any of that? If so, please update your question with what you have tried and what you are expecting in your output but not getting.

Comment: yes, I got the .avi file, but when I open file, it is blank video. Script didn't capture screen